# EC2 elastic load balancer out of service eroor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm able to view my webpage when I connect it directly from my instance but when I try to connect it via the load balancer it's not working. My instaces seems unhealty to loadbalancer. 
I've tried below health check rules: 
    Ping Target: HTTP:80/ 
    Ping Target: HTTP:80/index.php 
    Ping Target: HTTP:80/install.php

but result was the same. 
What could be the problem here..

Kind regards...

Comment: Under Instances tab; place where it shows status ; if you will rollover your mouse there; it will show you the reason also why it is unhealthy

Comment: We need more information to help you. What is under the `Status checks tab`? Does your instance has a `public DNS`?

Comment: Status: 0 of 2 instances in service

Comment: error message: Insstance has failed at least the UnhealtyThreshold number of health checks consecutively

Comment: Which HTTP status code is your application returning?

Comment: There is no responce. It's waiting a long time and web browser gives an connection error. I was able to connect my site if I bypass elastic load balancer and connect directly to the instance.